# Linear transformations relate to operator algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

$P(t)$ is a polynomial.

$A$ is a linear transformation on $P$.

$P(t) = a_0 +a_1t +a_2 t^2+\cdots + a_nt^n \qquad P(A) = a_0 + a_1A + a_2 A^2+\cdots+ a_n A^n$

I do not understand how t and A relate to each other except they "flow" in the same way. 
My problem is: If $A$ is a linear transformation on an n-dimensional vector space, then there exists a non-zero polynomial $p$ of degree $\le n^2$ such that $p(A) = 0$?

Comment: $n^2$?  Surely $n$ is enough.

Comment: @mookid Thanks for edit my question but it is "polynomial p of degree lesser and equal n^2" , not bigger

Comment: @user73195: does it remain any mistake?

Comment: No, that's good. Thank you. @Shuchang Thank you very much. I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

The linear space of $n\times n$ matrices over a field $\mathcal{F}$ is of dimension $n^{2}$ because you can think of a matrix as a vector with $n^{2}$ entries in it. Cosider the elements $I,A,A^{2},\cdots,A^{n^{2}}$.

I shortened this answer after I realized it was homework.

Comment: It wouldn't be bad to observe $\dim M_n(k)=n^2$ and the set $\{I,A,A^2,\ldots,A^{n^2}\}$ has $n^2+1$ elements. =)